# How to find mean and variance for probability problem with warranty?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am in a probability theory class and I'm stumped on a problem:

A warranty is written on a product worth \$10,000 so that the buyer is given \$8000 if it fails in the first year, \$6000 if it fails in the second year, \$4000 if it fails in the third year, \$2000  if it fails in the fourth, and zero after that. Its probability of failing in a year is 0.1; failures are independent of those of other years. What is the expected value of the warranty? Also find the variance?

I know how to find mean and variance, so I'm not asking anyone to solve the problem. What I am confused on is how to make a table with the correct y and p(y) values. When I used the monetary values for y-values and 0.1 for each p(y), the variance I calculated was in the millions. Any help on how to correctly set up a table is appreciated.